# IIS rewrite rule to redirect secure.domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

i have a site that used to use https://secure.example.com for all secure pages, now the entire site needs to be secure so now ANY url is secure under https://www.example.com

But have loads of legacy CMS content that isn't easy to manage so just wanted to put a rule in that ANY link that had https://secure.example.com/url.... rewritten to https://www.example.com/url....

Comment: What have you tried or you just want someone else to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this

```
    <rule name="secure to www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="https://secure.example.com/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^(secure)\.example\.com$" />          
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

but if i try this - https://secure.example.com/resp_register.aspx?prod=41&sid=7337826962595

it fails

But this works and diverts to the secure https version 
 - http://secure.example.com/resp_register.aspx?prod=41&sid=7337826962595